# How to fix "MessagingGatewayBadRequest" error in ARM template?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I am creating `namespace` and `service bus queues` using ARM template. I can create namespace successfully but getting following error while it tries to create queues:

> "code": "MessagingGatewayBadRequest",
> "message": "`400`SubCode=40000. Bad Request. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.

I am not able to find out the root cause of this error. There is nothing complicated about `queue` in my template, so not sure what is the root cause. Not seeing this error in  [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-exceptions#error-bad-request) as well.

**ARM template:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.5.6.12127",
      "templateHash": "15173749018276299351"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": ["Dev", "Test", "Prod"],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Environment for resource group"
      }
    },
    "resourceTags": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {
        "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
        "BillTo": "specialprojects",
        "Architecture": "AppService",
        "AlertName": "mgmt"
      }
    },
    "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Service Bus namespace"
      }
    },
    "queues": {
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Array of the Queue"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "name": "[toLower(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {},
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', toLower(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')), parameters('queues')[copyIndex()].name)]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "QueueCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('queues'))]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "lockDuration": "PT5M",
        "maxSizeInMegabytes": 1024,
        "requiresDuplicateDetection": true,
        "requiresSession": false,
        "deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration": true,
        "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT10M",
        "maxDeliveryCount": 10,
        "enablePartitioning": false,
        "enableExpress": false,
        "maxMessageSizeInKilobytes": 10240,
        "autoDeleteOnIdle": "PT48H"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', toLower(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')))]"
      ],
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**parameters.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "environment": {
      "value": "Dev"
    },
    "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
      "value": "c4p-dev"
    },
    "queues": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "dmp"
        },
        {
          "name": "smp"
        },
        {
          "name": "auction"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "MessagingGatewayBadRequest",
      "message": "<Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>SubCode=40000. Bad Request. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:06e867e5-289e-4fdd-956c-2b9684760455_G8, SystemTracker:c4p-dev.servicebus.windows.net:smp, Timestamp:2022-08-11T14:50:04</Detail></Error>"
    },
    {
      "code": "MessagingGatewayBadRequest",
      "message": "<Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>SubCode=40000. Bad Request. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:5fbdd148-e1c9-4db9-90ac-4ae9dc966ad9_G0, SystemTracker:c4p-dev.servicebus.windows.net:auction, Timestamp:2022-08-11T14:50:04</Detail></Error>"
    },
    {
      "code": "MessagingGatewayBadRequest",
      "message": "<Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>SubCode=40000. Bad Request. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:005c726d-e8fc-46cc-bd97-d9e688e9cab6_G17, SystemTracker:c4p-dev.servicebus.windows.net:dmp, Timestamp:2022-08-11T14:50:04</Detail></Error>"
    }
  ]
}
```

- [image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by creating `queues` separately. Meaning, following way (array) to create queue(s) is not supported by ARM template. This would work for `cosmos` and `blobStorage` ARM template though. Not sure why `serviceBus` is different.

```
  "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), parameters('queues')[copyIndex()].name)]",
  "copy": {
    "name": "QueueCopy",
    "count": "[length(parameters('queues'))]"
  },
```

**Correct way to create queue(s):**

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues",
  "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
  "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), parameters('smpQueue'))]",
  "properties": {
    "lockDuration": "PT5M",
    "maxSizeInMegabytes": 1024,
    "requiresDuplicateDetection": true,
    "requiresSession": false,
    "deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration": true,
    "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT10M",
    "maxDeliveryCount": 10,
    "enablePartitioning": false,
    "enableExpress": false,
    "maxMessageSizeInKilobytes": 10240,
    "autoDeleteOnIdle": "PT48H"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues",
  "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
  "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), parameters('auctionQueue'))]",
  "properties": {
    "lockDuration": "PT5M",
    "maxSizeInMegabytes": 1024,
    "requiresDuplicateDetection": true,
    "requiresSession": false,
    "deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration": true,
    "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT10M",
    "maxDeliveryCount": 10,
    "enablePartitioning": false,
    "enableExpress": false,
    "maxMessageSizeInKilobytes": 10240,
    "autoDeleteOnIdle": "PT48H"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
}
```